# how bind DataList template field in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, templates, bind, datalist

i want to bind a label -i created-  in Datalist template to col -named "item"-in my dataSource

i used the following code after several trials

```
        DataList2.DataSource = dt;  // my DataSource
        Label l1 = (Label)DataList2.FindControl("itemLabel");
        l1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["item"].ToString();
        DataList2.DataBind();
```

i got the following error at line '3' i am looking for the right expression

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Two things can happen. Your label is null or your dataTable is null.  which one?

Answer (score 1):

The label is null since it's `NamingConainer`(used for `FindControl`) is not the `DataList` but one of it's `DataListItems` (a `DataList` is used for multiple items).

So you need to `DataBind` it first, then you can handle it's [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx) event. There you are able to find the label and the underlying `DataItem`.

```
void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {

    // Retrieve the Label control in the current DataListItem.
    Label itemLabel= (Label)e.Item.FindControl("itemLabel");
    DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;
    String item = row.Field<string>("item");
    itemLabel.Text = item;
 }
}
```

Comment: can we just use some thing like 

foreach(DataListItem in Datalist2.items)

if the problem is with mulible items then make the bind ,however i tried that but the code expression is not right

Comment: You can also `DataBind` the `DataList` and `foreach` the items afterwards: `foreach(DataListItem item in DataList2.Items){}`. But i would use `ItemDataBound` instead for two reasons. It'll ensure that the code will always be executed on databinding and it is efficient since the loop is no extra-loop(`Item_Bound` will be called for every item).